# How to make the React component re render when the array inside the redux state object is sorted

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react application that uses redux for state management.
state object has multiple properties, one of them is an array. When I sort the array inside the state object, the component does not re render.
Below is the sample code: modifiedState is my redux state object where allGroups is an array

```
 let arry=modifiedState.allGroups;
 const newarry=arry.sort()
 modifiedState1={ ...modifiedState, allGroups: [ ...newarry ]};
 return modifiedState1;
```

Can someone pls point out what am I doing wrong. I am creating a new object with the spread operator which takes the object and updates the array with the sorted one.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the sorted version of your array, I suggest to move this logic into your mapStateToProps method.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how to do that? I am new to React-Redux. Basically in my application, the user can sort the columns on a page with the header like Name field, description, status, etc. I want to know if the user edits some of the col data. They should still see the new data in the sort order in the same way it was before. Currently what is happening is, once the user edit some data, the sort order is lost, since we do not store the sort key in the redux state. Can you pls suggest a better way to do that in Redux?

Comment: I'd be glad to show you a way to achieve that but I need a couple more information about your existing codebase. Could you please show me your api call method as well as your actions and reducer for this part, please ?

Also, are your familiar with hooks and functional components ? If not, that's perfectly fine but I need to know in order to provide an answer that is as clear as possible, since you're struggling with redux, I don't want to overwhelm you with unnecessary logic.

The component holding the code snippet you already provided would help as well but isn't mandatory.